# ExtJS Window setActive() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

**TL/DR:**

Calling `window.setActive(false)` does not set the window's `active` property to `false`.

**Full details:**

I have the following ExtJS class inheriting from `Ext.window.Window`:

```
Ext.define('WD.view.TbWindow', {
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',
    isTbWindow: true,

    title: 'Set Me!!',
    constrain: true, // constrain window to viewport
    autoShow: false,
    maximizable: true,
    minimizable: true,

    renderTo: 'main_panel-body',

    minimize: function() {
        this.hide();
        this.setActive(false);
        this.animateTarget.handleWinMinimize();
    },

    ...

});
```

Within function `minimize` above there's the call `this.setActive(false);`

I use Chrome developer tools to debug the code. Before executing the line `this.active` is `true`. After the line is executed it still is `true`. I'm using ExtJS 4.1.

Comment: have you tried reversing the order of `this.hide();` and
        `this.setActive(false);`?

also, do a `console.log(this)` in your `minimize` function, and make sure that `this` is evaluating to the window object.

Comment: it may also be a good idea to add an `alert("called")` to the `minimize` function, to make sure it is being called.

Comment: @Waltzy Thank you for you suggestions. Tried switching statements' order, and also checked that `this` is actually the Window. But neither fixed the issue.

Comment: That is odd.. @OffTopic, have you tried using Architect? http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
its quite good for debugging extjs.

Comment: You don't have any events that listen for the activate/deactivate that cancel the action (return false) do you?

Comment: @MattRoberts No. But this is a symptom of the actual problem. The problem is with the [Ext.WindowManager.getActive()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ZIndexManager-method-getActive) method. In fact, in the [web desktop example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/desktop/desktop.html) the Sencha guys actually do some not-so-nice coding to get the actual active window. I copied that code, and started supporting `windows` array in my code, and now everything works.

Comment: @Waltzy Do you use it? Is it worth it? I already use the Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @Josvic Zammit We use EXTJS pretty heavily at work, if you used Sencha designer I will have to note at this point that Architect is leagues and bounds better, its more of a full IDE than designer, It enforces best practices in application structure, and has some pretty nice support for Ext.Direct (if you use it), We still use chrome to debug but comparing development in Aptana (which we were previously using) to Architect is a no brainier, you don't spend your life referring to the API for all the trivial stuff like xtypes and layout config ect, so you can focus on the code, get a 30day trial!

Comment: Just to add to your conversation (not the question at hand) - I use Illuminations for Developers firebug plugin and must say it is a lifesaver when you need to visualize your component structure and layout - it also shows the records in the store very nicely.

Comment: Call me crazy, but the [Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window) mention nothing about a property called `active`, nor the code of `Ext.util.Floating` or `Ext.window.Window` seem to use such a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `Ext.WindowManager.getActive()` method. In fact, in the web desktop example the Sencha guys actually do some not-so-nice coding to get the actual active window. I copied that code, and started supporting windows array in my code, and that fixed my issue.

I've written a (and built extra functionality into) a `DesktopMgr` widget that inherits from `Ext.util.MixedCollection`, and acts as a "Desktop Manager", where "Desktop" implies any ExtJS container that is meant to handle multiple windows, activation, deactivation, navigating to the previous/next, etc.

You can download and use the `DesktopMgr` from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/4183342). Please let me know if you find ways to improve it (or bugs to fix!).

Answer (score 0):

There is no active property being set true or false in the source code, nor is it mentioned in the docs.

```
setActive: function(active, newActive) {
    var me = this;

    if (active) {
        if (me.el.shadow && !me.maximized) {
            me.el.enableShadow(true);
        }
        if (me.modal && !me.preventFocusOnActivate) {
            me.focus(false, true);
        }
        me.fireEvent('activate', me);
    } else {
        // Only the *Windows* in a zIndex stack share a shadow. All other types of floaters
        // can keep their shadows all the time
        if (me.isWindow && (newActive && newActive.isWindow)) {
            me.el.disableShadow();
        }
        me.fireEvent('deactivate', me);
    }
}
```